# Retrive a bit sequence and use it for a query

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have a table where one of the column, let's call it `source_id`, has type `bit(64)`.

I would like to get this value and use it into a subsequent query:

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("....");
rs.next();
ResultSet rs2 = statement.executeQuery(".... where source_id = " + rs.getBinaryStream("source_id"));
```

This code does not work, the problem seems to be the wrong type in `rs.getBinaryStream`, but i could also be wrong.

What can i do? Which is the right data type to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, `rs.getString()` should works as below since you are forming a `String` query statement to execute.

```
  ResultSet rs2 = 
     statement.executeQuery(".... where source_id = '" + rs.getString("source_id")+"'");
```

Comment: Ok String is the right type, but it as to be sorrounded with "'". If you can edit your answer!